# Did bedridden ever refer to a literal riding of a bed?

Tags: etymology

Looking into the origins of [bedridden](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bedridden), I found that the word comes from:

> Old English bedreda, -rida, < bed bed + rida rider, < rídan to ride. [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/16913#eid24545756)

I find that interesting, but still unsatisfying.  Is there a further explanation of why a gravely sick person would be called, essentially, a bed-rider?

Is it simply that people in the Middle Ages were more mobile, so it wasn't uncommon for the gravely sick to be transported to the new place without leaving bed? Could it be related to moving wounded soldiers?

Comment: That *is* an interesting question. I'd hazard to guess that "ride" was/is used because a person is essentially riding it, by definition, except for the fact that it doesn't move.  Although, you could make an argument that the bed does actually move through time, so the mere act of being atop it means you are actually riding it. I haven't found anything to support this theory, though.

Comment: Similar, more modern phrases include "desk jockey", "flying a desk" (ex pilots). No etymological relationship but the concept may be rather attractive.

Comment: The term isn't bed-riding though, it's bed-ridden. It isn't the person that rides, it's the bed: at least in the sense of being a burden. If you cannot move from bed, metaphorically the bed is controlling you.

Comment: Isn't one of the definitions of 'ride' "to be conditioned; depend (usually followed by on)" So a bedridden person would depend on a bed.

Comment: Back in the days before bicycles, to ride something meant  to be carried by an animal or by one or more persons. So if horse can carry me to my destination, someone who is confined to bed can only be carried (ridden) by an animal or by two or more people. In the Bible there is the story of the paralysed man who had been taken by friends to see Jesus. He was certainly bedridden, but his bed was carried...

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't quite follow- carried and ridden are not equivalent. If a horse carries you, *you* are carried, the *horse* is ridden. The horse may also be flea-ridden. Ridden in this sense is more like 'burdened by'.

Comment: @Spagirl it was a bit of a wild guess, I had the page opened for a while before I posted my comment and later saw yours. But how do you explain the "ride" meaning which OED cites? *Ridden* meaning "filled with or containing something unpleasant or unwanted" is dated 1653, whereas bedridden is dated prior to 12th century.

Comment: According to Merriam-Webster,  the 7th definition of the transitive verb, [ride](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ride), is *carry*.

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ride says: *Old English ridan "sit or be carried on" (as on horseback).* I don't think this implies the bed must move or the person goes for a ride to some destination in the bed. It seems to me simply, that the person sits atop it.

Comment: The term "disease-ridden" does not mean that people go around riding diseases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that ***bedridden*** is derived from Old English term *bedrida* which later morphed into *bed-rid*, a person who typically and regularly *keeps* a bed

From [Folk Etymology](https://books.google.it/books?id=fXrlvr_kPXwC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=etymology%20bedridden&source=bl&ots=uwiUu91fVQ&sig=Wy9AEWDtMPiL91K2977bsgSrV10&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ4o-d8qnNAhVHiSwKHVt4Ajo4ChDoAQggMAE#v=onepage&q=etymology%20bedridden&f=false) (subtitled: *verbal corruptions or words perverted in form or meaning, by false derivation or mistaken analogy*) by Rev. A. Smythe Palmer, written in 1969

> **bedridden** the passive form of this word is puzzling. As it stands it would seem to denote one that was ridden or pressed by his bed, rather than one who lay upon it—the paralytic man as he returned home with his burden, rather than as he came for cure, borne of four.
>
> It is the **A. Sax.** *bedrida*, *bedreda*, or *bedredda*, **a derivative from *ridam*, to ride, rest on, or press**; so denotes one who habitually keeps his bed: O.Eng. “*bedered-man* or woman. *Decumbens*, *clinicus*, ”  *Prompt. Parv.* (cf. *bedlawyer*, Decumbens, *ID*.). Similarly, *hofrede* is one who keeps his house (*hof*), a sick man. **The form *bed-rid* was probably mistaken for a past partc. and then changed to *bed-ridden.***

Walter W. Skeet (1835-1912), author of *[The Concise Dictionary of English Etymology](https://books.google.it/books?id=aDhGlKL3h00C&redir_esc=y)*, also stated that **bedridden** was derived from Old English *bedrida* and acquired erroneously the *pp* suffix **-en**

> **bedridden** (E.) M.E. *bedreden*, used in the pl. (P.PI. B. viii.85); *bedrede*, sing. (Ch. C. T. 7351.) **Corrupted from A.S. *bedrida*,** lit. ‘a bed-rider;’ one who can only ride on a bed, not on a horse — A.S. *bed*, a bed; and *rid-a* *, one who rides, from *ridan*, to ride.

Comment: Link to Skeat's book courtesy of Archive.org https://archive.org/stream/bub_gb_4ZkRAAAAIAAJ#page/n51/mode/2up/search/bedridden

Answer (score 4):

According to the OED, one meaning of the word "ridden" is "afflicted or beset with", as in "fog-ridden" or "angst-ridden".  I would imagine that bedridden most likely has always meant afflicted by not being able to leave one's bed.

Comment: But according to this [source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ridden), *ridden*, meaning *filled with or containing something unpleasant or unwanted" is dated 1653, whereas [*bedridden*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bedridden) is dated before the 12th century. So, while today we understand the expression to mean "to be afflicted", what about speakers of Middle English?